# Looking forward to my first Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Had a fun idea for my first riley riddle.

> My prefix is against it all
>
> My Infix SEEs my EYE, did you hear what I did there
>
> My suffix waited a long time, but did not mind

I can't wait untill someone solves it!

Necessary hint

> The suffix sounds similar to the word it describes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> Anticipation

My prefix is against it all

> **Anti** - means opposed to or against.

My Infix SEEs my EYE, did you hear what I did there

> **Ci** - as mentioned by jc1850 (SEE, EYE)

My suffix waited a long time, but did not mind

> **Pation** sounds like patience, as mentioned by Cashbee

Title

> Anticipation could be described as the act of looking forward to something, also ties in with the line "I can't wait untill someone solves it!" which is an extra hint.

Comment: That would indeed be the correct answer and great work on seeing that I referenced 2 times to the actual word :).

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> CONSTIPATION?

My prefix is against it all

> CON - Contra

My Infix SEEs my EYE, did you hear what I did there

> STI - (far fetched) is pronounced similar as "CI" which is probably the correct infix ("My Infix Cs my I")

My suffix waited a long time, but did not mind

> PATION - sounds like patience

Answer (score 3):

*This answer would not be the way it is without the other answers. They each deserve an upvote! I have unfortunately run out of votes (DVL12).*

Could you be

> **CONSCIENCE**?

`My prefix is against it all`

> **CON** (thanks to @[Cashbee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49661/cashbee)).

`My infix SEEs my EYE, did you hear what I did there?`

> **CI** (thanks to @[jc1850](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52152/jc1850)).${}^1$ The word **conscience** also refers to the third **eye**, and there is a saying "**see** no evil, **hear** no evil (and speak no evil)". 
>  <sub>${}^1$**SEE** + **EYE** = **C** + **I** = **CI**.</sub>

`My suffix waited a long time, but did not mind`

> **SCIENCE**. Science can take ages (simply put, from experimenting to rock formations). Also, the word **mind** has to do with **conscience**, the latter word sounding quite like **PATIENCE** (thanks to @[Cashbee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49661/cashbee), again).

Comment: @upvoter I encourage that you upvote the other answers, too!

Comment: Not the word that I was looking for but nice guess. I see you got some experience here and I want to ask since I'm kinda new to this site. Should I say which parts you have answered correctly or just say some parts are correct and you guys figure it out from there?

Comment: @mrdeadsven you can say whatever you want, buddy. I mean, it is your puzzle at the end of the day, but perhaps give out hints only after say one to three days if it has not been solved, which is unlike this case. That is only my suggestion, but like I said before, it is your rules. Thanks for asking, though :P

Comment: Yay first time I helped :) Your explanation of the infix is unclear to me. Isn't it (rot13)orpnhfr 'FRR' naq 'RLR' fbhaq yvxr P naq V?

Comment: @Cashbee yes, indeed. I have edited to include the explanation, as I realise it might not be that obvious as I found it to be :D

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

Guessing the infix is:

> CI (C sounds like see, I sounds like eye)